# Split exact short sequence

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, exact-sequence

If the given short exact sequence
$$ 0\to M'\xrightarrow{f}M\xrightarrow{g}M''\to0 $$
splits then why is $M$ isomorphic to the internal direct sum of $M'$ and $M''$?

I know that if this sequence splits then $M$ is the internal direct sum of the image of $f$ and $\ker f'$ where $f'$ is the right inverse of $f$ and also $M$ is the internal direct sum of the kernel of $g$ and the image of $g'$ where $g'$ is the left inverse of $g$ then how can I say that $M$ is the internal direct sum of the image of $f$ and kernel of $g'$? How can I say this to get the desired result by exactness?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: First of all, if the sequence splits, then $f$ has a left-inverse and $g$ has a right-inverse.

Comment: By the Splitting Lemma, we have that $M \cong f(M') \oplus g''(M''),$ where $g'' : M'' \to M$ is the right-inverse of $g.$ Considering that $f$ is injective by the exactness of the sequence and $g''$ is injective by the splitting of the sequence, we have that $M' \cong f(M')$ and $M'' \cong g''(M'')$ so that $M \cong M' \oplus M''.$

Comment: Is it that that if a given sequence splits,then the reverse sequence also splits.If yes,then how?

Comment: That is correct. If the sequence $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ splits, then we have that $B \cong A \oplus C.$ But this gives an exact sequence $0 \to C \to B \to A \to 0$ such that $B \cong A \oplus C,$ i.e., this sequence is split.

Comment: And why is that so?..why does this reverse sequence split?

Comment: Is this condition if and only if?..If yes..then it's fine..N could you please tell why is that condition iff..the book i am reading just says that if an exact sequence splits then the condition holds...I can't find the converse of it